# Unable to build docker container on synology, as synology uses 7z not unzip

Tags: docker, synology, azerothcore

I had set a little docker project for myself and thought it may be fun to try and get azerothcore running on my synology.
I have cloned the repository, but was unable to run the acore.sh script to build the docker containers as synology uses 7zip, and acore.sh threw an error because it couldn't unzip the archives.
I wondered if it was possible for me to find out what scripts were attempting to unzip things, and change the commands to call 7z?

running acore.sh throws an error because it can't find unzip. however synology use 7zip.

`user@DS920:/volume1/docker/wow/azerothcore-wotlk$ ./acore.sh docker build NOTICE: file </volume1/docker/wow/azerothcore-wotlk/conf/config.sh> not found, we use default configuration only. Deno version check: /volume1/docker/wow/azerothcore-wotlk/apps/bash_shared/deno.sh: line 18: ./deps/deno/bin/deno: No such file or directory Installing Deno... Error: unzip is required to install Deno (see: https://github.com/denoland/deno_install#unzip-is-required).`

Comment: Have you tried reading the link provided by the error: Citing from deno's docs *"**When does this issue occur?**
During the `install.sh` process, `unzip` is used to extract the zip archive."*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message points to `/volume1/docker/wow/azerothcore-wotlk/apps/bash_shared/deno.sh` and says

> Error: unzip is required to install Deno

If you look into `deno.sh` script you'll see the command which installs `deno`:

```bash
curl -fsSL https://deno.land/x/install/install.sh | DENO_INSTALL="$AC_PATH_DEPS/deno" sh
```

If you download this script you'll see `unzip` there.

I would suggest trying to install unzip, e.g. like described here: [How to install IPKG on Synology NAS](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/127148)

Comment: Thanks! I managed to install unzip using the instructions here: https://darencard.net/blog/2018-08-14-entware-synology/. I have now come across a different issue, as synology seems to use the older `docker-compose` utility rather then `docker compose` but that is probably a matter for another post

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried:

```
sudo opkg install unzip
```

Comment: Hi - opkg wasn't on my system, however, I have just managed to install it and then unzip by following this article. https://darencard.net/blog/2018-08-14-entware-synology/

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass the `./acore.sh` dashboard with standard docker commands.

to build:

```bash
$ docker compose --profile app build
```

to run:

```bash
$ docker compose --profile app up # -d for background
```

Using standard docker commands has the added side benefit of not needing to install deno locally since it's already being installed to the container.